# Best way to do conversion from IQueryable of a type to an array of a converted type?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, type-conversion, iqueryable

I am using the Entity Framework and want to put the elements of an IQueryable into an array of a **converted** type.
Having `NormalType` as first type and `ConvertedType` as the converted one, the "conversion" is done this way:

```
//Creates a NormalType object based on ConvertedType instance.
NormalType nt = new NormalType (ctInstance);
// Returns a new ConvertedType instance,
//based on the content of the NormalType instance.
ConvertedType ct = nt.getConvertedType();
```

Now, I want to convert a list of type NormalType into a ConvertedType array
 (`IQueryable<NormalType> -> ConvertedType[]`).

My first thought is to classically iterate through the `IQueryable<NormalType>`, put the data into a `List<ConvertedType>` and then convert the second list to an array using `ToArray()` method:

```
//Rest of code....
List<ConvertedType> convertedTypeList = new List<ConvertedType>();
//normalTypeIQueryable is of type IQueryable<NormalType>
foreach(NormalType normalType in normalTypeIQueryable) 
{
  convertedTypeList.Add(normalType.getConvertedType());
}
ConvertedType[] convertedTypeArray = convertedTypeList.ToArray();
```

My second thought is to do it using `ToList()`, `ConvertAll(...)` and `ToArray()` in a one-liner:

```
normalTypeIQueryable.ToList().ConvertAll(n => n.GetConvertedType()).ToArray();
```

I think that the last one will lead into more than one loops through the conversions though.

Which of those two ways is better in terms of performance? Is there any even better alternative?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: The `GetConvertedType()` creates a new instance of a converted type based on the data the `NormalType` contains, in a "deep-copy" manner.

Comment: I'd go for the second solution.
It depends on the complexity of GetConvertedType

Comment: The better solution is `list.Select(i => i.GetConvertedType()).ToArray()`. Which for practical purposes does exactly the same as your manual `foreach`.

Comment: Won't work if you don't do a ToList() before.

Comment: I think it works, as IQueryable provides Select on its API.
@Jon, please give an answer on the question about it, explaining why it is the best. It seems great to me. Thanks!!

Comment: @gillesemmanuel: What exactly won't work and why?

Comment: @NickL.: It would work even if `Select` was not provided, as `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. I added an answer.

Comment: It depends actually but usually you have an IQueryable to then make a query to some data source and the data source won't know the property "GetConvertedType()". Not sure about though...

Comment: Select works in my case, as GetConvertedType() is used only on a set that has this defined implementing an interface, so no problem on it.

Comment: @gilesemmanuel you are right. After testing this on my code, LINQ does not recognize the GetConvertedType().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. What you want to do is project the values inside the source sequence into different values, then put the resulting sequence into an array.

LINQ does projection with `Select`, so the simplest, most natural, and (at least as long as you are going to use LINQ) most performant way to write it is:

```
var result = input.AsEnumerable().Select(i => i.GetConvertedType()).ToArray();
```

This is effectively equivalent to the manual `foreach` loop in your example.

Comment: After testing this on my code, LINQ does not recognize the GetConvertedType(). Please update your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @NickL.: Interposing `.AsEnumerable()` should fix that. Edited the answer.